# How to get Current loaded fragment tag in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hi i am trying to get Current loaded fragment tag in my app for this i wrote below code but i am getting null pointer exception why i am getting null pointer exception can some one help me please

### my code:-

```
intializingPhoneFragments(new SettingsListViewFragment(), "SettingsListViewFragment");


 private void intializingPhoneFragments(Fragment fragment,String tag) {

        try {

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentManager.popBackStack();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout_master, fragment, tag);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

            Fragment currentFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.frame_layout_master);
            if(currentFragment.getTag().equals("SettingsListViewFragment")) {
            }
            else {

            }
}
```

Comment: Is your currentFragment null or currentFragment.getTag() is null?

Comment: currentFragment is also coming null

Comment: Thats because you are finding the fragment in wrong manner. R.id.frame_layout_master is not the Id of fragment.
You find fragment by the tag you assigned to it.

Comment: how can i do this can u explain with some code